# How to find Adjoint of Operator

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, adjoint-operators

I want to learn how to find adjoints for operators. I was told the adjoint of the operator $M(f(x))=-f'(x)-xf(x)$, using integration by parts, is $N(f(x))=f'(x)-xf(x)$.

Main question: How do I find the adjoint?

I don't see how to use the definition here. The definition states that the adjoint $N$ is defined by $\langle Mx,y\rangle=\langle x,Ny \rangle$. What is an inner product of this form? I don't know how $\langle Mx,y\rangle$ is defined.

Minor Question: How is integration by parts being employed?

Comment: The typical sort of inner product that gets used on functions has the form $\langle f, g \rangle = \int f(x) g(x) \, dx$. The use of integration here is the source of the integration by parts.

Comment: It's not clear to me what $f,g$ should be for the example above.

Comment: $f, g$ are two arbitrary functions. The adjoint is defined by the condition that $\langle Mf, g \rangle = \langle f, Ng \rangle$ for all $f, g$.

Comment: There must be some context for the problem; what space does $f$ come from?

Comment: @copper.hat I'm interested in densities. In this example, $f$ is the density for the standard normal distribution: $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-x^2/2}$. I'm interested in the space containing all densities.

Comment: Write out the expression $\langle M f,g \rangle$ and use the fact that $(f(x)g(x))' = f'(x)g(x)+f(x)g'(x)$, and, presumably, $f,g$ vanish as $|x| \to \infty$. In particular, you have something like $\int f'g = - \int f g'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us rewrite the relationship between $M$ and its transposed operator $N$ with $x$ and $y$ replaced by $f$ and $g$:

$$ \langle Mf,g\rangle=\langle f,Ng \rangle$$

It suffices to check that:

$$\int (Mf)(x)g(x)dx=\int f(x)(Ng)(x)dx$$

Or:

$$\int (-f'(x)-x f(x))g(x)dx=\int f(x)(g'(x)-x g(x))dx$$

which is true, by using integration by parts.

Remark : in the integration by parts, we have assumed that the "integrated part" [...]$_a^b$ is zero.

- if the integration domain is $\mathbb{R}$, it will be necessary for this that all functions $f,g \cdots$ tend to $0$ at infinity (the case underlined by @copper.hat).
- if the integration domain is a bounded interval [$a,b$], one will have the following conditions: $f(a)=g(a)=f(b)=g(b)=0$.

Comment: I am tempted to answer "by trial and error". In fact, it depends very much on the way $Mf$ is defined. But in 99.99% of cases you have to use integration by parts.